# How to change tooltip style in jQuery vmap?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jqvmap

I created a map with [jQuery.vmap](http://jqvmap.com/)
and set the `showTooltip: true` setting.
By default, this tooltip has a black background and white font;
I can't inspect element tooltip in Chrome in order to change css style for it.

How can I change the tooltip style in jQuery.vmap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [supplied CSS](https://github.com/manifestinteractive/jqvmap/blob/master/dist/jqvmap.css), it seems that the tooltips are called "labels". The CSS to edit (or override) is:

```
.jqvmap-label
{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #292929;
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif, Verdana;
    font-size: smaller;
    padding: 3px;
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

Comment: thank you,I don't see included library's :) , just Inspect element is my eye & I should add new eye to see all librarys :).All thing is ok!